# What's wrong in nginx configuration?

Tags: ruby, linux, nginx, jekyll

I am trying to host a jekyll site in digital ocean using nginx server. But after modifying `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file nginx is unable to restart.

Here is the location of jekyll site: `/home/blog/_site`

Location here is dump of default file http://pastebin.com/VxFGx3Sf

What's am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the root directive. I moved my site from `/home/blog` to `/usr/share/nginx/html3`, then restart the server.

**`html3`** directory contains all the contents of the jekyll site

**`root`** directive should point to **`_site`** directory inside **`html3`**

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html3/_site
```

Answer (score 1):

The "listen 45.55.213.107:80" line looks strange to me:

Try with

```
server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen 80;
    server_name 45.55.213.107;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: still fails to restart

Comment: What's the output of nginx restart? Have you checked the /var/log/nginx/error.log?